# Django ORM lookup syntax

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have a model Fruit, and fruit has orchards.

```
class Fruit():

  orchards = models.ManyToManyField('Orchard', blank=True)
```

Each orchard belongs to a farm:

```
class Orchard():
  farm = models.ForeignKey('Farm', verbose_name='Farm', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Every fruit is a seedling

```
class Seedling():
   fruit = models.ForeignKey('Fruit', editable=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here is my attempt:

```
queryset = Seedling.objects.all().filter(fruit__orchards__in__farm=farm_id)
```

This gets me an error `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: in`
Anyone able to clear up my query? Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You filter with:

```
queryset = Seedling.objects.filter(fruit__orchards__farm=farm_id)
```

so *without* the [**`__in`** lookup [Django]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in). If you filter over a *one-to-many* relation, or a *many-to-many* relation, you filter *existentially* over one of the related elements.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly it. So simple.